# AngularJS factory object is not automatically updating view through controller

Tags: angularjs, websocket, factory

So I have this issue that I have been scratching my head over for a few days now, it seems that I am either finding really outdated code, something is broken or I plainly have no clue what I am doing.

I can't for the love of me get my controller to use the model from my factory to update the view. The only thing that happens, is that the default model is displayed and never updated.

This is a summary of the relevant parts of my factory:

```
var entryData = {
    "postMessage": []
    , "setPeerCount": {}
    , "nudge": {}
};
ws.onmessage = function(message) {
    listener(JSON.parse(message.data));
};
function listener(rpc2) {
    console.log(rpc2);
    if(rpc2.hasOwnProperty("method") && entryData.hasOwnProperty(rpc2.method)) {
        if(type.set[rpc2.method] !== undefined) {
            entryData[rpc2.method] = rpc2.params;
        }
        else if(type.add[rpc2.method] !== undefined) {
            entryData[rpc2.method][entryData[rpc2.method].length] = rpc2.params;
        };
        console.log(entryData)
    }
};
return entryData;
```

My controller (socket is the factory, sockItToMe is the test app name):

```
sockItToMe.controller('peerCount', ['$scope', 'socket', function($scope, socket){
     $scope.peerCount = socket;
}]);
```

My view:

```
<div ng-controller="peerCount">
    {{ peerCount }}
</div>
```

The output I get in my HTML:

```
{"postMessage":[],"setPeerCount":{},"nudge":{}}
```

The output I get from console, by reading the object directly:

```
Object {postMessage: Array[0], setPeerCount: Object, nudge: Object}
nudge: Object__proto__: Object
postMessage: Array[1]0: Object
    message: "Welcome"__proto__: Object
    length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
setPeerCount: ObjectpeerCount: "3"
```

Comment: Perhaps this here does help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658490/angular-websocket-and-rootscope-apply

Comment: Amazing, that worked perfectly, is it possible to do a $apply(), without doing it on the entire $rootscope?
Also would you mind writing an answer, so I can check it as the solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional information to [the link posted I posted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658490/angular-websocket-and-rootscope-apply): Although you can just do $scope.$apply() instead of $rootScope.$apply() it will internally call $rootScope.$digest() so we don't get any performance optimization here. What you can do is call $scope.$digest(). This will be executed on the current scope and updates only the child elements. But the parent scope won't get updated until the whole digest loop is run again. If you need that I think you have to do $scope.apply().

[Concerning stackoverflow: Is it now better to upvote the comment or to accept an answer? Because my answer is more or less just a link pointing to the right answer. I will leave that up to you ;)]

Comment: You just get one on both of them. :P
And it's more so the question gets marked answered and so other people can find the answer more easily. :)