# service only works after `$rootScope.$appy()` applied

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-directive

I am loading the template from `angular-service` but that's not updating the `template` unless i use the `$rootScope.$appy()`. but my question is, doing this way this the correct approach to update the templates?

here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('modalService', function( $rootScope ) {


  this.hide = function () {

    this.show = false;


  }

  this.showIt = function () {

    this.show = true;

  }

  this.setCategory = function ( category ) {

     return this.showPath = category+'.html'

  }

  this.showCategory = function (category) {

    this.setCategory( category )
    $rootScope.$apply(); //is this correct?
  }

})

app.controller('header', function($scope) {

  $scope.view = "home view";

});

app.controller('home', function($scope, modalService) {

  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.service = modalService; 

});

//header directive

app.directive('headerDir', function( modalService) {

  return {
      restrict : "E",
      replace:true,
      templateUrl:'header.html',
      scope:{},
      link : function (scope, element, attrs) {


         element.on('click', '.edit', function () {
            modalService.showIt();
            modalService.showCategory('edit');
         });

         element.on('click', '.service', function () {
           modalService.showIt();
           modalService.showCategory('service');

         })

      }
  }

});

app.directive('popUpDir', function () {

  return {
    replace:true,
    restrict:"E",
    templateUrl : "popup.html"
  }

})
```

Any one please advice me if i am wrong here? or can any one show me the correct way to do this?

click on links on top to get appropriate template to load. and click on the background screen to close.

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3o9aAP49pjyZDoSjNPig?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use Angular's error handling, and you know your changes shouldn't propagate to any other scopes (root, controllers or directives), and you need to optimize for performance, you could call $digest on specifically your controller's $scope. This way the dirty-checking doesn't propagate. Otherwise, if you don't want errors to be caught by Angular, but need the dirty-checking to propagate to other controllers/directives/rootScope, you can, instead of wrapping with $apply, just calling $rootScope.$apply() after you made your changes.

Refer this link also [Angular - Websocket and $rootScope.apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658490/angular-websocket-and-rootscope-apply)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)** for handling the click events.

*Template:*

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-click="showEdit(item)">Edit</div>
  <div ng-click="delete(item)">Edit</div>
</div>
```

*Controller:*

```
....
$scope.showEdit = function(item){
....
}
$scope.delete = function(item){
....
}
```

If you use jquery or any other external library and modify the $scope, angular has no way of knowing if something has changed. Instead if you use ng-click, you let angular track/detect change after you ng-click handler completes.

Also it is the angular way of doing it. Use jquery only if there is no other way to save the world.