# Passing rootScope value from one controller to another controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass the value from controller to another using $rootscope what I did is first I intialize rootScope like this

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.emp=0 ;
});
```

then I am changing the value of rootScope in one of my controller like this this

```
app.controller("datatableController", function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, $http, $rootScope) {
 $scope.update = function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $scope.message = $http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/employee/view', data).
            then(function (response) {
                $scope.userEdit = response.data;
                $rootScope.emp=$scope.userEdit[0].id;
                alert($rootScope.emp);
            });
        window.location.href = "updateEmployee.html";

    };
});
```

then i am trying to access this changed $rootScope.emp value in my second controller but getting the value that i set at the time of initialization which is 0

```
app.controller("UpdateController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

    $scope.userid=$rootScope.emp;
    alert($scope.userid);
});
```

Comment: are you sure its getting updated inside datatableController

Comment: Are you sure about the order in which the controller code executes? Does datatableController execute before UpdateController. And if you want to share data between controllers, I think having a service is a better approach.

Comment: I think the service is not returning success and that's why it is never entering into then function and hence the value of `$rootScope.emp` not getting updated. Try adding debugger at these points.

Comment: yes It's inside datatableController

Comment: this is not the case as you can see i put the alert condition which outputs the id of employee but in update controller alert i only get 0

Comment: I am sure about the order because the when datatableController executes then it redirect me to the page of updateEmployee where I am trying to get the updated rootScope value .

Comment: You might have used `#` in href somewhere and because of it the page gets reload and the rootScope values are lost. Can I see your code how you are redirecting from one page to another?

Comment: window.location.href = "updateEmployee.html"; i am redirecting to updateEmployee.html through this . and yes its get reloaded

Comment: Check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/1188/.  issue is with your route change. You need to change route using angular way.

Comment: Actually i  am not using ng-view because i did'nt create any master page each page is individual but i want to use same angular module but different controller to pass the value .

Comment: Wrong aprroach. Understand the Framework features first.

Comment: Must use service when sharing data between controllers. $rootScope is not a good way to do that.

Comment: and if page reload than updated service value will be reinitialize or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
app.controller("datatableController", function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, $http, $rootScope) {
 $scope.update = function (data) {
    alert(data);
    $scope.message = $http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/employee/view', data).
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.userEdit = response.data;
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                $rootScope.emp=$scope.userEdit[0].id;
            });
            alert($rootScope.emp);
        });
    window.location.href = "updateEmployee.html";

};
});
```

[Detailed Answer can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658490/angular-websocket-and-rootscope-apply)